# Click to activate VS2005 tool panes in Vista causes double-click

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, windows-vista

I've been putting up with this forever and suddenly I thought: Maybe someone else has run across this!

In Visual Studio 2005 on Vista x86, when I click on a tool pane that does not have focus, it does a double-click. Does this with the property window, toolbox, error list, output window, and so on.

Some things I've noticed:

- This happens on a totally fresh install of VS2005, which rules out my add-ins and macros.
- It happens on two different Vista machines but not on any XP machine I've used.
- I don't use any weird Logitech mouse helper apps or other system mouse-hooking background things.
- This is unique to VS2005: no other app that I use has this issue.

UPDATED:

- I have tried running as an admin. One one of my Vista machines I have UAC disabled - no difference.
- VS2005 SP1 is installed, Vista SP1 is installed, and the Vista update for VS2005 SP1 is there too. Fully patched.
- I have looked through all the release notes I could find and notes about 2005 from Microsoft, but nothing is in there about weird GUI behavior.

Has anyone else run into this? My workaround is to right-click on the tool pane first, then I can do what I need in there. Bleh.

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed the VS2005 SP1 Update for Vista?  Are you running as Administrator?  [Here's the low-down from Microsoft on Vista/VS2005](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/aa948853.aspx).

Comment: Yes and yes. Any other ideas I could try?

Comment: not really, when I moved to Vista I converted my XP dev machine to a VM; I keep Vista to 2008 only :(

Answer (score 0):

Sounds hardware-y.  Have you ever adjusted your mouse sensitivity or anything like that?  Have you tried with a second mouse to see if it happens with that one?